# What is the disadvantage of using websocket/socket.io where ajax will do?

Tags: ajax, node.js, websocket, socket.io

Similar questions have been asked before and they all reached the conclusion that AJAX will not become obsolete. But in what ways is ajax better than websockets?

With socket.io, it's easy to fall back to flash or long polling, so browser compatibility seems to be a non-issue.

Websockets are bidirectional. Where ajax would make an asynchronous request, websocket client would send a message to the server. The POST/GET parameters can be encoded in JSON.

So what is wrong with using 100% websockets? If every visitor maintains a persistent websocket connection to the server, would that be more wasteful than making a few ajax requests throughout the visit session?

Answer (score 30):

I think it would be more wasteful.  For every connected client you need some sort of object/function/code/whatever on the server paired up with that one client.  A socket handler, or a file descriptor, or however your server is setup to handle the connections.

With AJAX you don't need a 1:1 mapping of server side resource to client.  Your # of clients can scale less dependently than your server-side resources.  Even node.js has its limitations to how many connections it can handle and keep open.

The other thing to consider is that certain AJAX responses can be cached too.  As you scale up you can add an HTTP cache to help reduce the load from frequent AJAX requests.

Comment: I believe this is right.  In applications where you don't need bi directional communication, ajax requests will be much more easier on the server.  Also, consider that when HTML5 offline persistence becomes available (basically the same time as websockets becoming more available) that web applications would only sync with the server as necessary.

Answer (score 27):

**Short Answer**
Keeping a websocket active has a cost, for both the client and the server, whether Ajax will have a cost only once, depending on what you're doing with it.

**Long Answer**
Websockets are often misunderstood because of this whole "Hey, use Ajax, that will do !". No, Websockets are not a replacement for Ajax. They can potentially be applied to the same fields, but there are cases where using Websocket is absurd.

Let's take a simple example : A dynamic page which loads data after the page is loaded on the client side. It's simple, make an Ajax call. We only need one direction, from the server to the client. The client will ask for these data, the server will send them to the client, done. Why would you implement websockets for such a task ? You don't need your connection to be opened all the time, you don't need the client to constantly ask the server, you don't need the server to notify the client. The connection will stay open, it will waste resources, because to keep a connection open you need to constantly check it.

Now for a chat application things are totally different. You need your client to be notified by the server instead of forcing the client to ask the server every x seconds or milliseconds if something is new. It would make no sense.

To understand better, see that as two persons. One of the two is the server, the over is the client. Ajax is like sending a letter. The client sends a letter, the server responds with another letter. The fact is that, for a chat application the conversation would be like that :
"Hey Server, got something for me ?
- No.
- Hey Server, got something for me ?
- No.
- Hey Server, got something for me ?
- Yes, here it is."
The server can't actually send a letter to the client, if the client never asked for an answer. It's a huge waste of resources. Because for every Ajax request, even if it's cached, you need to make an operation on the server side.

Now the case I discussed earlier with the data loaded with Ajax. Imagine the client is on the phone with the server. Keeping the connection active has a cost. It costs electricity and you have to pay your operator. Now why would you need to call someone and keep him on phone for an hour, if you just want that person to tell you 3 words ? Send a goddamn letter.

**In conclusion Websockets are not a total replacement for Ajax !**
Sometimes you will **need** Ajax where Websocket usage is absurd.

**Edit : The SSE case**
That technology isn't used very widely but it can be useful. As its name states it, Server-Sent Events are a one-way push from the server to the client. The client doesn't request anything, the server just sends the data.

In short :
- Unidirectional from the client : Ajax
- Unidirectional from the server : SSE
- Bidirectional : Websockets

Comment: what if you use websockets only, but decide sometimes to manually close the connection to save resources?

Comment: As stated in this answer, using websocket isn't bad, it's just a matter of "do you need bidirectional communication". If the websocket is inactive, the server might decide to close it anyway, and the client will have to reopen it if it needs to.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. Your whole point is to say "websocket can be absurd to use if you don't require bi-directional, because it let a connection opened". So my question is: what if you decide to implements WS anyways (to be future-proof for example), and manually close the old connections, to handle ressource management ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand either. There's nothing preventing you from using both Ajax and WS on the same page, they are just designed for different kind of communication.
In theory you could load everything using WS and close the connection yourself once it's loaded but I can't really see the benefit of doing that over a simple Ajax call or an SEE event.

Answer (score 19):

Personally, I think that websockets will be used more and more in web applications instead of AJAX. They are not well suited to *web sites* where caching and SEO are of greater concern, but they will do wonders for webapps.

Projects such as DNode and socketstream help to remove the complexity and enable simple RPC-style coding. This means your client code just calls a function on the server, passing whatever data to that function it wants. And the server can call a function on the client and pass it data as well. You don't need to concern yourself with the nitty gritties of TCP.

Furthermore, there is a lot of overhead with AJAX calls. For instance, a connection needs to be established and HTTP headers (cookies, etc.) are passed with every request. Websockets eliminate much of that. Some say that websockets are more wasteful, and perhaps they are right. But I'm not convinced that the difference is really that substantial.

I answered another related question in detail, including many links to related resources. You might check it out:

[websocket api to replace rest api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806263/websocket-api-to-replace-rest-api/6829366#6829366)

Answer (score 8):

I think that sooner or later websocket based frameworks will start to popup not just for writing real-time chat like parts of web apps, but also as standalone web frameworks. Once permanent connection is created it can be used for receiving all kinds of stuff including UI parts of web application which are now served for example through AJAX requests. This approach may hurt SEO in some way although it can reduce amount of traffic and load generated by asynchronous requests which includes redundant HTTP headers.

However I doubt that websockets will replace or endanger AJAX because there are numerous scenarios where permanent connections are unnecessary or unwanted. For example mashup applications which are using (one time) single purpose REST based services that doesn't need to be permanently connected with clients.

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing "wrong" about it.

The only difference is mostly readability. The main advantage of Ajax is that it allows you fast development because most of the functionality is written for you.

There's a great advantage in not having to re-invent the wheel every time you want to open a socket.

Answer (score 3):

WS:// connections have far less overhead than "AJAX" requests.

Answer (score 1):

As other people said, keeping the connection open can be overkill in some scenarios where you don't need server to client notifications, or client to server request happens with low frecuency.

But another disadvantage is that websockets is a low level protocol, not offering additional features to TCP once the initial handshake is performed. So when implementing a request-response paradigm over websockets, you will probably miss **features that HTTP (a very mature and extense protocol family) offers**, like caching (client and shared caches), validation (conditional requests), safety and idempotence (with implications on how the agent behaves), range requests, content types, status codes, ...

That is, you reduce message sizes at a cost.

So my choice is AJAX for request-response, websockets for server pushing and high frequency low latency messaging

Answer (score 1):

If you want the connection to server open and if continuous polling to the server will be there then go for sockets else you are good to go with ajax.

Simple Analogy :
Ajax asks questions(requests) to server and server gives answers(responses) to these questions. Now if you want to ask continuous questions then ajax wont work, it has a large overhead which will require resources at both the ends.