# Socket.io and node.js example in android

Tags: android, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I am new to socket programming i have to use socket.io and node.js to connect with my server host in android so can anyone please just describe me the programming example of how to connect to server in android. And if possible please give some help regarding node.js and socket.io. As i have searched everywhere on google but not able to find out the proper example.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can just have your web service be REST base.

Your Android application can just talk to your web server via REST and receive data json or xml whatever you fancy.

So with node.js you should set up routes.

An example would of a route would be

www.example.com/users via GET post would return a list of users either in JSON/XML

For your android application you need a library, I believe there's a built in one already, to make request for certain routes such as www.example.com/users via GET method and write the logic to expect JSON or XML and parse that.

I just googled this:

Android: https://github.com/koush/ion

As for node.js you just have to build route...

I think is would be better:

[websocket api to replace rest api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806263/websocket-api-to-replace-rest-api)

It actually invalidate my answers sorry, REST and websocket api are different.

I have no clue what problem exactly you have. But you should break your problems down to small part. And google and search for answer for each smaller part which would make your life easier to google.

Get your webservice up first so that your android software can consume stuff, build a prototype and then build a prototype of android app that consume data from that webservice.

Comment: Can you please just give me any link of simple example of android that connects to server using socket.io

Comment: So I broke your big problem down to two smaller problems. And googled ion and a stackoverflow question for node.js. You should really break this question down into smaller pieces so you can solve it. Otherwise you're going to have a hard time solving it.