# Node.js: I already use socket.IO for chat, what about transporting Web-pages also through it?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

So. I have got web-chat working on socket.io. I'm thinking of using it also for web-pages transportation for not to create more requests to the server. How do you feel about it?

.. Or, probably, one additional request per minute won't make sense, but it's easier to work on web-pages in Express. Anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think of websockets as being a good fit for web applications, not web sites. Transferring web pages would lose the ability to bookmark or to utilize SEO techniques.

However, I certainly think that using websockets in place of AJAX calls is a direction to move in. I've provided some resources and information in answers to similar questions:

[websocket api to replace rest api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806263/websocket-api-to-replace-rest-api/6829366#6829366)

[What is the disadvantage of using websocket/socket.io where ajax will do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848642/what-is-the-disadvantage-of-using-websocket-socket-io-where-ajax-will-do/6829575#6829575)

Comment: Yes. I meant exactly something like that.

Comment: And, so - I won't have an ability to handle more than ~6500 connections on the same time on one server? For example chat.

Answer (score 1):

Those pages could not be found by any search engine.
For private areas (where you have to be logged in), why not? I think the only disadvantage would be, that you could not load multiple things together.

Comment: Multiple things together? If I put <img> tags into page would they load parallel, isn't it? So, what would load not together?